# "Turn off" an Azure App Service and Azure SQL Server to reduce cost

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-appservice

I have a client with a web app running in Azure App Services and a SQL Azure database that the web app uses.

This client will not be using these for the foreseeable future and would like to minimize costs. I know I can "turn off" the app service, but I'm not sure what impact that has on pricing. Also I'm not sure if there are similar options for the SQL Azure database.

Is there a way to reduce the costs for these services (hopefully to zero) without deleting them from the Azure subscription?

Comment: For Azure SQL, you can look at the serverless tier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview. It will "turn off" if unused after a configurable period of time. Downside of it is it is more expensive when in use. You'll still have to pay for storage though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure SQL Database (DTU-model) you can [scale down](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scale-resources#overview) the database service tier to Basic (if the database has less than 2 GB in size) which cost USD$5 a month or to S0 if the database has 256 GB or less) which cost USD$15 a month.

You can also [export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export#:%7E:text=%20The%20Azure%20portal%20%201%20To%20export,the%20server%20containing%20the%20database%20being...%20More%20) the Azure SQL Database (as bacpac) to an Azure Storage Account and then delete the database. If you need the database in the future, you just import the database from the storage account.

To spend less with App Service you can lower pricing tier for the App Service Plan and apply it as shown on the image below:

[image]

Comment: Stopping an App Service does NOT change it's pricing.  The pricing is dictated by the underlying App Service Plan, and that gets charged regardless of whether the apps within in are Running or Stopped.  However, just like with Azure SQL, you can "Scale Down" the App Service Plan to a cheaper tier.